# Convert Stata "egen, group" to SAS

Tags: sas, stata

I am trying to find the equivalent of the Stata code "egen group" in SAS. 
The goal is:
I have three variables x, y, and z. I want to create a new variable which will assign a different ordinal number for each combination of values of x, y, and z. How can I do this in SAS?

Answer (score 0):

If you order your data by `x`, `y`, and `z`, SAS knows exactly where the groups `x`, `y`, and `z` start/end. You can use this to create unique identifiers.

Let's make some sample data. This data purposefully has duplicate values to illustrate how `first.` works.

```
data have;
    do x = 'a', 'b', 'c';
        do y = 'd', 'e', 'f';
            do z = 'g', 'h', 'i';
                output;
                output;
            end;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

**Single-Threaded Unique IDs**

This is the most likely case for you. This applies if you're running code in Base SAS.

First, sort the data by `x y z`.

```
proc sort data=have;
    by x y z;
run;
```

Next, create your identifiers. We'll tell SAS that the data is ordered by `x y z`. Since `z` is nested within `y` and `x`, if we reach the first value of `z`, we've reached a unique combination of `x y z`.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by x y z;

    if(first.z) then id+1;
run;
```

Output:

```
x   y   z   id
a   d   g   1
a   d   g   1
a   d   h   2
a   d   h   2
a   d   i   3
a   d   i   3
...
```

`id+1` is a special SAS shortcut called a sum statement and is equivalent to the following code:

```
retain id 0;
if(first.z) then id = id+1;
```

**Multi-threaded Unique IDs**

This applies if you're running code in SAS Viya in CAS. You need to add `_THREADID_` to the ID to make it unique. For example:

```
cas;
libname casuser cas caslib='casuser';

data casuser.have;
    set have;
run;

data casuser.want;
    set casuser.have;
    by x y z;

    if(first.z) then _id+1;
    
    id = catx('_', _THREADID_, _id);

    drop _id;
run;
```

Output:

```
x   y   z   id
a   d   g   15_1
a   d   g   15_1
a   d   h   15_2
a   d   h   15_2
a   d   i   15_3
a   d   i   15_3
...
```

Comment: Definitely works!  I think there's a quicker way using a proc, but my `idgrp` idea with proc means didn't work.  If the data size is really big though there's probably other options - maybe one of the clustering procs would do it for example.